# select and get most recent post ID from wpdb

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

How do I select and get the most recent post ID from $wpdb?

I imagine something like this, but have no idea what to put into the ???

```
$recent_post_id = $wpdb->get_var( 
        "
        SELECT ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE ?????
        "
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the simplest and fastest way to do it is to use `MAX()` if by the *most recent* you mean a record with the maximum id.

```sql
SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM $wpdb->posts
```

or if you need to get it by `post_date`

```sql
SELECT id 
  FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_date = 
(
   SELECT MAX(post_date) 
     FROM $wpdb->posts
)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use order by here to retrieve the latest inserted values in descending order, `WHERE` clause is used for matching criteria.

```
SELECT ID
FROM $wpdb->posts
ORDER BY ID desc
```

OR

```
SELECT ID
FROM $wpdb->posts
ORDER BY your_date_column desc
```

It will be efficient to use `LIMIT` with this query to limit the result.

```
SELECT ID
FROM $wpdb->posts
ORDER BY ID desc
LIMIT 10               #It will give you latest 10 records from database.
```

Comment: works perfectly! I thought there might be a variable like 'current_row' which I could use with the 'WHERE' clause. But if ordering is the only way, I'll go for it...